# How to put conditional formatting in a cell from another excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

It's hard to describe what I want, I'm not really familiar with Excel condition terms but it is basically just like this:

```
Worksheet= Dr. castro patient consultations

A        B     C      D       E
January  1     2014   Lopez   Sam



Worksheet= Patient Library

A        B     Jan      Feb       E
Lopez    Sam   =if 'Dr. castro patient consultations'!A1 = January then +1
```

I know my question isn't very clear, but I really want to do this project to make our clinic's monthly assessment better. pls help me guys. thanks A LOT.

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but I still don't understand the second worksheet.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to summarize patient visits by month?

Comment: Is the issue that Conditional Formatting is not allowing a reference to a different sheet in the condition formula?

Answer (score 1):

Excel will not allow a bare reference to another sheet in a conditional formatting formula.

[image]

To get around this, you can create a Named Range to represent the data on the other sheet. Conditional formatting allows references to named ranges, even if they are found on a different sheet.

*Create Named Range:*

[image]

*Use Named Range in Conditional Formatting Rule:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. I think you have a list of bookings in the first worksheet and want a formula that would give you the number of bookings that are in January with a particular doctor. If that's right, then the following formula would work:

```
=COUNTIFS('Dr. castro patient consultations'!A:A,"January",'Dr. castro patient consultations'!D:D,"Lopez",'Dr. castro patient consultations'!E:E,"Sam")
```